# i dont wan to keep dbname before each table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have installed my php website with database in IIS,  windows 2012, The problem is it is accepting if i mention db name before table name for each query in my website. example below

```
select userid,profile_id,email,first_name,last_name,password,login_flag,usertype 
from reqsbook.user 
where email='$email'
  and password='$password' 
  and usertype='$usertype'
```

actually i used to run this website in linux web server but as per my client requirement i have installed it in iis server.
please let me know is there any possibility for remove db name before table in all queries in my project or can i keep db name at once place for universal

Comment: You need to set the active database on your connection.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**!

Comment: When you call `mysqli_connect` or `new PDO` to open the connection, you can specify the default database. Then you don't have to put the database name in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Three ways to do this, assuming your database name is `reqsbook`.

1. Give the SQL command `USE reqsbook;` immediately after connecting from php to your dbms, before you give any `SELECT` or other queries.
2. if you're [connecting with `mysqli_`,](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) use something like this:

   `$mysqli = new mysqli('hostname', 'username', 'REDACTED_PASSWORD', 'reqsbook');`
3. If you're [connecting with PDO,](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) try something like this

   `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=hosthame;dbname=reqsbook', 'username', 'REDACTED_PASSWORD');`

If you're connecting with `mysql_`, well, stop doing that unless you want your customer's application pwned by cybercriminals.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer this is very use for me